# Associate measure group with 2 role playing dimensions

Tags: ssas, mdx, ssas-2012

I have two fact tables – charges and payments and both of these fact tables are in the cube (as measure groups). i have one date dimension in the cube and 2 role playing date dimensions that are built off of the same date dimension:

1. charge date
2. payment date.

when i look at the data by say charge date and i filter by 2012 Jan, i want to see all the charges in 2012 Jan and all payments associated; but the cube shows all the payments that exist in the system. I have linked these two measure groups using a "transaction dimension" but that doesn't have a date.

any ideas how to get the date filter to work on both these measure group? thanks in advance!

note: a single charge can have multiple payments and vice versa. In other words, 10 different charges could have one pay date and there could be 10 payments associated with one charge..

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [link](http://www.bp-msbi.com/2010/10/avoiding-multiple-role-playing-date-dimensions/) .

You'd need to create 2 date dimensions based on your calendar which would resemble the 2 date filters that you would need. The difference would be the relationship between the fact, and the referencing date key. This would mean that you'd require the relationship to be:

- Charges Fact : The charge date key
- Payments Fact : The payment date key

This would mean that you would have 2 date role playing dimensions that you can filter on. So in that case you would be able to filter on both dates in the charges, and also in the payments.

Comment: thanks Mez. I already have two date dimensions (role playing) and that is how the relationship is setup. Are yo suggesting that i need to create two date dimensions (physically)?
Edit - let me go through the article in detail and see if I figure this out. thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you have any other suggestion on this? Creating a new "event dimension" suggested by the article is beyond what I have permissions for and I don't think I'll be able to convince the ETL team.
Anyone else? I posted this question on the MSDN forums a few weeks ago but didn't get any help.

Comment: Having 2 date dimensions configured with a different date key in SSAS reading from the same physical calendar is normal in these cases. Create a proof and see if it works for you in a development environment. Otherwise, there aren't any other suggestions.

Comment: that is exactly how I have it setup now but when I filter for charge date, say Jan 2014, all payments regardless of the date show up from the cube.

Comment: Then you have something incorrectly setup in your relationship, or the relationship does not exist. I assume both the facts are related to a common user? i.e. a user can have both payment and charge?

Comment: Yes both fact tables link to a common dimension called customer.